# Is there a way to Read and Write the same line in a NodeJS file stream?

Tags: node.js, fs

For a node generator project, I want to place the word export in front of a function when it doesn't exist. Now I used the package [line-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-reader) because of its clean use. I don't think this package offers the option to **read and write the same line and save it to the same file**. Now I'm looking for advise or help how to implement a read and write stream for the same line or is the only option to create two different streams?

So what i would want to accomplish is when the line above includes generate en the next line doesn't includes the condition export. Export should be added to the start of the line.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import lineReader from 'line-reader';

const curFile : string = 'currentFile.ts'
let nextLine: boolean = false;

lineReader.eachLine(curFile, async (line: string, last: boolean | undefined): Promise<void> => {
    if (nextLine) {
        if(!line.includes('export')){
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(curFile, {
                encoding: 'utf8',
                autoClose: true,
            });
            await writeStream.write(`export ${line}`);
            writeStream.end();
        }
        nextLine = false;
    }

    if (line.includes('generate')) {
        nextLine = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import lineReader from 'line-reader';

const curFile: string = 'currentFile.ts';
const secFile: string = 'otherFile2.ts'
let nextLine: boolean = false;

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(secFile, {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    autoClose: true,
});
lineReader.eachLine(
    curFile,
    async (line: string, last: boolean | undefined): Promise<void> => {
        if (nextLine) {
            if (!line.includes('export')) {
                writeStream.write(`export ${line}`);
            } else {
                writeStream.write(`${line}`);
            }
            nextLine = false;
        }

        // check if line includes generate
        if (line.includes('generate')) {
            nextLine = true;
        }

        // If the last rule has been reached end stream and remove original file and replace it with the sec file.
        if (last) {
            writeStream.end();
            replaceOriginalFile(curFile, secFile)
        }
    },
);


function replaceOriginalFile(originalPath: string, newPath: string) {
    // remove original file
    fs.unlinkSync(originalPath);
    // rename file to replace original
    fs.rename(newPath, originalPath, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}
```